# How to adapt the architecture of a website and have suitable hosting along with it to meet increasing users?

Tags: architecture, websites, scalability, large-scale-project, website-performance

Say you start a web site on shared hosting and it increases in popularity which might cause it to become unavailable as the number of accesses increases.

So as a developer how do I figure out when the limits are being reached and what can I do about it in terms of the architecture with the suitable hosting solution to accompany it?

This is a "holistic" question I've had difficulty finding answers to and it shows from reactions here that other people aren't clear about it either.

I guess I'm seeking best practises or a guide as it's a very practical issue that someone will encounter if they do get something going that takes on the scale of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Related: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/ and http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html

Comment: This should be moved to Super User I think. The right answer is probably something like: if this is a real problem, your web host will reach out to you because your traffic will affect the other users on the shared host.  You upscale the hosting by asking the shared hosting company what their non-shared hosting service offering is.  If your growth is too fast for going to a larger dedicated host then you need to hire someone.

Comment: @RibaldEddie Superuser says it's for computer enthusiasts and power users so it would not fit. This is both a programming and hosting (more admin then user) question. From what I've read, the site design may need to be adapted as a site evolves.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for sharing these great links :)

Answer (score 6):

Just a quick note on terminology:

- Scaling **up** refers to improving the hardware.
- Scaling **out** refers to adding more hardware in a load balanced environment.

In the web world, we tend to scale out the web servers to handle more load. If your application is stateless (i.e. no session variables), you should be able to clone the web server and have the load distributed by a load balancer at the head of the solution stack. If it is stateful (you made a bargain with the devil and started using session state), you can still use load balancing, but you'll also have to apply some form of session stickiness to the load balancer.  With either of these options, in theory you could add a hundred web servers and handle 100 times the traffic.

Scaling out the web farm is even easier if you are using a Cloud/docker sort of solution. Web sites that work with Docker need to use a limited subset of O/S functionality (e.g. compile against .NET Core instead of .NET framework). But the benefit is that they run completely virtually.  Instead of living on a physical computer, they live in docker containers, which can be spun up automatically as load increases.

That leaves the database. It's harder to scale out the database due to concurrency and data consistency issues. So the database server tends to get scaled **up**, e.g. adding more CPUs, memory, and SAN capacity.

Comment: Session state is only an issue (for this particular aspect) if you store it on the web server.

Comment: True, it's only an issue for the load balancer if the session state is in proc. However, out-of-proc session has its own issues, e.g. if you use SQL state then you have limited ability to scale it out (just like the DB server).

Comment: The spring framework has a session module that permit to handle the session in a Redis store. Redis is light & fast key/value database, so it fits for that job.If you need to handle sessions through multiple web server with quite some load, it is probably one of the best solution for it.

Comment: "Wait, you sold your *soul* for a stateful application?  How much of your soul?"  "Just a bit."

Comment: @JohnWu thanks for taking a shot at an answer. What a lot of people here might no realize is that this is a very practical question that might face a developer if he is the sole person running a web site. I simply don't know what to do if a site increases in popularity so it continues to work fine and I've read that big sites do all sorts of stuff on both the software and hosting side to deal with this. For example, Facebook switched away from it's original PHP solution to something more exotic as the social network grew.